# Pair image with text and center inside a parent

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to replicate this construct:
http://kaitnieks.com/images/divme.png

The question consists of 2 parts:

1) How to create the middle box that expands to just the necessary size for containing the red image and the blue text;

2) How to center the said box both horizontally and vertically inside the green box;

Additional requirements: the solution has to work fine on IE7 and should somewhat work on IE6 (might be imperfect, but the elements should at least be visible).

I might be able to do #2 using one of the techniques described on the web but I'm not so sure about #1, although intuitively it seems like it should be the easy one.

Comment: Are there any constraints on `green`?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean by constraints - if you're asking whether its size is known, then the answer is "in some cases". If there is no technique for making this work for green with unknown size, then I can change the requirements a bit and fix the size of the green.

Comment: I'm trying to put the red and blue inside a box, floating them, using align tag etc, but as soon as I start changing the text's box from inline to something else, it expands to whole green's width, however if I leave it as inline, it aligns image to the first line of the text, not the overall text element.

Comment: Use a table.  Most of the people around here will gasp and clutch their chest at the mere thought of using a table, but when it comes to vertically centering content CSS fails horribly, and tables are still the best tool for the job, particularly if you need to support IE6/7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's one for #1](http://jsfiddle.net/TgBXE/)

First: I use inline elements, because in IE7 `display: inline-block` only works on elements that are naturally inline (though it's not pretty, you can put block level elements in them, I've decided not to do so). I set the size of the small box, set a `-height/2` top margin on it, and position it halfway through.

As for #2, if you have a fixed height for green, since the whole thing is an inline-block, you can update it [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/TgBXE/3/). It sets the `line-height` to the height of the element, and positions the black vertically centered. If you need, you can set a `text-align: center` on `.green` as well.

I forgot IE7 doesn't support min-height. I've added a padding with the height of green to the container and a negative margin to the text block, so it won't show on it.

[Final fiddle with min-height fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/TgBXE/4/) (forgot IE7 doesn't support that, also you can change the length of the text by clicking `blue`).

You have to add an `&nbsp;` to the `.container` though, otherwise it won't be centered.

Comment: This might work, let me dust off the laptop with IE7 and check :)

Comment: It doesn't entirely work (see http://kaitnieks.com/images/fiddleresult.png) but I like the general technique. Since the red is going to be an image, I can try to use background image instead of absolute box. Thanks, this is starting to get somewhere.

Comment: Nice idea! If you add `left: 0;' to the leftBox css, it will also work on IE7.

Comment: Ok, I used Wesley's suggestion and your fiddle /2/ and this is the result: http://kaitnieks.com/images/fiddleresult2.png. #1 now works correctly when text field is higher than image but not when image is higher than text (text should be centered vertically just like the image). The black box though is not being centered in green box neither vertically nor horizontally yet.

Comment: Unfortunately /3/ is the same as /2/ - black box is in the upper left corner, not center. I think IE7 ignores green's line-height.

Comment: It's better - container is now centered horizontally but vertical centering is still problematic.

Comment: In some circumstances there must be characters (for example `&nbsp;`) next to the vertically aligned element. This has just become one.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it was close enough and I managed to hack around its deficiencies.

Answer (score 0):

1) An element will automatically adjust its size to its content if you don't set width nor height it

2) Centering the box horizontally should be possible is my feeling; however you'll need some javascript to center it vertically if the height is variable. So you might as well do the positioning of the whole box using javascript.

Centering vertically with variable height is a bitch. If you insist in trying it with just css, [this](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html) link is a good read.

Comment: Regarding 1, the problem is that content is 2 elements. I'm not sure how to put them side by side while keeping the box that wraps them dynamically sized. If it was just text then sure, no problems.

Comment: Ah ok.. If you take @wrock his example and add `left: 0;` to the .leftBox css, it will work on IE7 as well.